# Unable to access flutter doctor from my flutter console

Tags: flutter

i downloaded flutter to my windows 10 and i extracted it to my C:\ directory, am able to check the flutter version from the flutter console, but whenever i try flutter doctor it gets stucked with this message. I will be glad if anyone can fix this.
Thanks
[Flutter Console Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ce2sh.png)

Comment: Have you downloaded plugin for flutter

Comment: you need to follow this way for windows : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-flutter-on-windows/

Comment: big thanks @Ruchit it worked... i followed this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65785014/15411904